# Extraction of Restrictions from an XSD document using java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, jaxb

is it programmatically possible to get restrictions values applied on an XSD element in an XSD file using **java** ?
in the XSD example below, **how can i extract the pattern value related to element with name "code1"** ?

'''
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

```
<xs:element name="customer">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="stringMaxSize5"/>
    <xs:element name="age"  type="stringMaxSize2"/>
    <xs:element name="code1"  type="Text_FIN_16x_Type"/>
    <xs:element name="code2"  type="Identifier_FIN_4Ea_Type"/>
            <xs:element ref="phone-number" maxOccurs="2"/>
         </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="phone-number">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="stringMaxSize5">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="stringMaxSize2">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="2"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Text_FIN_16x_Type">
    
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="16"/>
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z/\-\?:\(\)\.,&apos;\+ ]{1,16}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

 <xs:simpleType name="Identifier_FIN_4Ea_Type">
    
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="4"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="4"/>
        <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{4}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

</xs:schema> '''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how much you know about the schema. If you know everything except the pattern then writing an XPath expression is very easy.

If all you know is the type name "Text_FIN_16x_Type" then it's rather more difficult (because, for example, the type might be defined as a union type, or as a restriction of some other global type, or as a restriction of a local anonymous type).

I all you know is the element name "code1" then it's harder still, because there are any number of ways the type of an element can be defined - and it's not even guaranteed that there is only one declaration of "code1" in the schema (in your schema, it's a local element declaration and therefore doesn't have to have a globally unique name).

Generally you have a much better chance if you try to access a compiled schema that's already been processed by a schema processor. If you're in Java then you could consider:

(a) the Xerces schema access API (https://www.w3.org/Submission/2004/SUBM-xmlschema-api-20040309/)

(b) the Saxon SCM file format, which represents a compiled schema component model as an XML document.

(c) the saxon:schema() extension function, which provides an XPath API to explore a compiled schema.

The advantage of going in at this level is that there are a lot of details you don't need to worry about, because they've already been taken care of - xs:include and xs:import, named model groups and attribute groups, substitution groups, etc etc.